# How do I calculate a percentage of a number in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms. I want to calculate percentage of a number by using simple math. For example:

Calculate 25% of 80.

```
double result` = (80 / 100) * 25
```

Result = 20

Another example: 25% of 30 = 7.5

However, when I tested this method of calculating the percentage, I always get zero result in `MessageBox.Show()`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double result;             

    result = (80 / 100) * 25;
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

The `MessageBox.Show()` always shows shows zero result, I tried `MessageBox.Show(result.ToString("F"))` and `MessageBox.Show(result.ToString("0.00"))` and the result still zero. I have no idea why I am getting zero. Please help me how to calculate the percentage.

Thank you

Comment: Please look up integer division. You will find the answer here. 

http://www.dotnetperls.com/divide

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem is integer division.

Integer division results in an integer. If you want to get the results cast to respective double/float/decimal.

```
result = ((double) 80 / 100)* 25;
```

Comment: Minor issue. Please cast the divisor or the dividend.

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers in the calculation are of type `int` they need to be of type `double` or else the result will automatically be converted to `int`.

As soon as one of the inputs is of type `double` the result will also use that type and not drop the digits after 0.

Try this:

```
result = (80.0 / 100.0)* 25.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below extension method

```
public static double Percent(this double number,int percent)
{
    //return ((double) 80         *       25)/100;
    return ((double)number * percent) / 100;
}
```

Use like this

```
double result = 25.0.Percent(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problem in your code.
First is integer division which stated by other answers.
Second is your math logic which no one stated.

Use following code that fixes both of problems.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double result;             
    result = (25f / 100f)* 80;
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString()); //prints 20
}
```

Comment: Where's the difference in "your" math logic?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.
I know the problem has already been solved but this is how I managed to get around it :)

```
int number = 80;
int percentWanted = 25;
float divideBy = 100 / percentWanted;
float percentOfNumberAsNumber = number / divideBy;
```

Comment: How is that different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641508/14989571) other answer?

Comment: @Shunya It uses different maths. In the other answer you divide by the total then times by the percentage you want, here you create a number to divide by. Also, when I used that method with variables instead of hard coded numbers it always seemed to return 0. This way worked for me.